# Open CV Tutorial on IOS not working, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv

I am trying to write a simple openCV app for iOS, but I am having trouble with using openCV functions in XCode. They will throw a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1), or not work entirely. I am using the processImage sample from the tutorial and that doesn't even work. I am using XCode 7.3 beta and believe I have installed openCV 2.4.11 correctly.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>


using namespace cv;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CvVideoCameraDelegate>
{
    //IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    CvVideoCamera *camera;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CvVideoCamera* camera;

@end
```

ViewController.mm

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>


@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize camera;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.camera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView: self.imageView];
    self.camera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;

    self.camera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
    self.camera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.camera.defaultFPS = 60;
    self.camera.grayscaleMode = NO;
    self.camera.delegate = self;
    self.camera.useAVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = YES;

    self.imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    [self.camera start];
}


#pragma mark - Protocol CvVideoCameraDelegate
#ifdef  __cplusplus


- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image;
{
    // Do some OpenCV stuff with the image
    Mat image_copy;
    cvtColor(image, image_copy, CV_BGRA2BGR);

    // invert image
    bitwise_not(image_copy, image_copy); // ERROR IS THROWN HERE, BUT IT 
                                         // WILL ALSO THROW ON THE CVTCOLOR
                                         // IF I REMOVE THIS LINE
    cvtColor(image_copy, image, CV_BGR2BGRA);
}

#endif


-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems in your code. Maybe try downloading the newest version of the framework from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/3.1.0/). Note that the header file `cap_ios.h` has moved to `videoio` which means you'll have to import: Hope that helps

`#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>`